# How to detect object index with touch?

Tags: ios, swift, touch

I am developing a puzzle game where I want to detect Index of the image where touch is happend and I was doing that from objective-C tutorial and it says:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
       UITouch* mytouch = [[ touches allObjects] objectAtIndex : 0 ];
       }
```

So this way he do it but in swift how can I write this?

Please help me about this.

This is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RqEfG9_5R4)  for that tutorial If any one want to see for more information.

Go direct at 22:00 and you will find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the same code in swift. Take a note that `touches` array can by empty and the `first` property returns optional value. Thats why I use optional bidding.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touches = touches.allObjects as [UITouch]

    if let myTouch = touches.first {

    }
}
```